# passing arguments to different CLI app from node.js script

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-scripts, yargs

I'm creating a node.js CLI to automate my tasks , one of the tasks is `git` and the init, add,commit, remote are working just fine now the problem within the push .

Note I use shellJS to execute the commands .

the code I tried is :

```
shell.exec('git push origin master');
```

now the problem is I get this error :

```
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument
```

now how to pass the username to the git push ? or simply run the git push from inside out the script I mean when I finish the others tasks I should use something to run the git push like running a bat file (I tried that too).

Comment: If you `cd` to your project directory and run `$ cat .git/config` does it return the correct remote `url` for the project on _github_. For example `url = git@github.com:username/project-name.git`.

Comment: @RobC I guess your url is the right one, i get this url  `url = https://github.com/pro-devel/testing-clinix.git` :\

Comment: No, your `url` is the correct one. The `url` I provided was just a pseudo example.

Comment: @RobC so do you have sny solutions ?

Comment: No not specifically, however the discussion in this thread starting  [here](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-deployer-git/issues/71#issuecomment-299627697) regarding the `could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument` error may be worth exploring.